# ¿Como probar App link facebook si todavia no as subido app en google play?

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

Estoy desarrollando una app Android y es mi primera vez que la voy a subir a Google play. Quiero implementar la funcionalidad de App link de Facebook. Hay alguna manera de poder hacer pruebas con el link de mi app? O de subierla primero para luego implementarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes subir tu app a la playstore y dejarla en estado alpha, así solo tu y tus testers podrán tener acceso a ella, ya que no se publicará hasta que pases la app a producción.

Entonces así puedes hacer la pruebas que quieras. E incluso hacer pruebas con otras APIs de google